Why do I keep getting a Segmentation Fault from trying to access /dev/mem in ARM64 on the Raspberry Pi 4?
I've been working at this program for months, and I've fixed many errors, errors with alignment, other segmentation faults, and I've gotten down to this one, where it throws a segmentation fault when I try to open /dev/mem, I can see the "Failed to obtain file                                                                descriptor for /dev/mem" error that I made for that purpose in the elf file, I'm not sure why, all of the parameters seem to be correct, I'm on raspbian btw, any ideas?
.text
.include "gpioLedMacros.s"

.global _start

.align 4
_start:
        mmapdevmem
        adds x9, xzr, x0
        nanosleep
        gpiodirectionout pin17
loop:
        gpioturnon pin17
        nanosleep
        gpioturnoff pin17
        nanosleep
        b loop
.data
pin17:
        .word 4 /* pin offset value in select */
        .word 21
        .word 17
.align 4
pin22:
        .word 8 /* pin offset value in select */
        .word 6
        .word 22
.align 4
//Execution File

.include "fileMacros.s"

.equ prot_read, 1
.equ prot_write, 2
.equ map_shared, 1
.equ pageLength, 4096
.equ setregoffset, 28
.equ clrregoffset, 40

/* mmap creates a virtual page of memory in a specified, or non specified
   directory, with a varible page size/length for the page created, then returns
   a virtual address for the virtual page created */
.macro mmapdevmem
        openat devmem, readwrite+execute, stdin
b1:
        adds x4, xzr, x0 /* mov devmem file descriptor into x4 */
        /* Error handling code */
        bpl 1f
        mov x1, #1
        ldr x2, =devmemerrmessage
        ldr w2, [x2]
        mov x8, #0x40
        svc 0
        mov x0, #2
        mov x8, #0x5d
        svc 0
1:
        ldr x5, =gpioBaseAddress/* Load the base gpio address into x5 */
        ldr x5, [x5]            /* Load the value from the base gpio address */
        mov x0, #0              /* move 0 into x0 for stdin */
        mov x1, #pageLength     /* move 4096 which is the page length into x1 */
        mov x2, #3              /* move protect read, and protect write permissions into x2 */
        mov x3, #map_shared     /* move the map shared value into x3, which is 1 */
        mov x8, #0xde           /* load the value for the mmap syscall into x8 */
        svc 0                   /* call mmap */
        adds x9, xzr, x0        /* Obtain file descriptor returned from mmap */
        bpl 2f
        mov x1, #1
        write x1, errmessage, len
2:
        /* x0 = 0
           x1 = 4096
           x2 = 3
           x3 = 1
           x4 = fd for /dev/mem
           x5 = value in baseGpioAddress
           x8 = 0xde / mmap
           x9 = mmap returned file descriptor */
.endm

.macro nanosleep
        ldr x0, =timeamount
        ldr x1, =timeamount
        mov x8, #0x65
        svc 0
.endm

.macro gpiodirectionout pin
        ldr x2, =\pin   /* Load the pin number into x2 */
        ldr w2, [x2]    /* Load the value of that pin number into x2 */
        ldr w1, [x9, x2]/* Load into x1 the value of the file descriptor of mmap offset by the value of the pin that you're trying to set */
        ldr x3, =\pin   /* Load the pin number into x3 */
        add x3, x3, #4  /* add the amount to shift to the pin number */
        ldr x3, [x3]    /* Load the value of the shift amount of the pin into x3 */
        mov x0, #0b111  /* Load 3 1 bits (which is the clear value) into x0 */
        lsl x0, x0, x3  /* Shift the 3 1 bits by the pin shift amount */
        bic x1, x1, x0  /* Use the 3 bits to clear the mmap offset file descriptor value */
        mov x0, #1      /* Move 1 into x0 for the out value */
        lsl x0, x0, x3  /* Shift the out bit by the pin shift amount */
        orr x1, x1, x0  /* orr the out bit with the mmap file descriptor pin offset value */
        str w1, [x9, x2]/* store the out bit into the mmap file descriptor pin offset */
.endm

.macro gpioturnon pin
        mov x2, x9
        add x2, x2, #setregoffset
        mov x0, #1
        ldr x3, =\pin
        add x3, x3, #8
        ldr x3, [x3]
        lsl x0, x0, x3
        str w0, [x2]
.endm

.macro gpioturnoff pin
        mov x2, x9
        add x2, x2, #clrregoffset
        mov x0, #1
        ldr x3, =\pin
        add x3, x3, #8
        ldr w3, [x3]
        lsl x0, x0, x3
        str w0, [x2]
.endm

.data
devmem:
        .asciz "/dev/mem"
timeamount:
        .dword 0
timeremaining:
        .dword 10000000
gpioBaseAddress:
        .dword 0xfe200000
errmessage:
        .asciz "Couldn't obtain file descriptor for /dev/mem\n"
len = .-errmessage
devmemerrmessage:
        .asciz "Couldn't obtain devmem file descriptor\n"
len2 = .-devmemerrmessage
//gpio macro file

equ dfd, -100
.equ stdin, 0
.equ readwrite, 0666
.equ execute, 0200

.macro openat filename, flags, permissions
        ldr x0, =dfd
        ldr x1, =\filename
        mov x2, #\flags
        mov x3, #\permissions
        mov x8, #0x38
        svc 0
.endm

.macro fchmod fd, permissions
        mov x0, \fd
        ldr x1, =\permissions
        mov x8, #0x34
        svc 0
.endm

.macro read fd, fillblock, length
        mov x0, \fd
        ldr x1, =\fillblock
        mov x2, #\length
        mov x8, #0x3f
        svc 0
.endm

.macro write fd, string, length
        mov x0, \fd
        ldr x1, =\string
        mov x2, \length
        mov x8, #0x40
        svc 0
.endm

.macro fsync fd
        mov x0, \fd
        mov x8, #0x52
        svc 0
.endm

.macro close fd
        mov x0, \fd
        mov x8, #0x39
        svc 0
.endm
// File macro file

I've put it through gdb, and it says the segmentation fault happens at 0x0000000000410100, when I objdump it and go to 410100, it looks like this 000a0058 210a0058 c24680d2 030080d2, other than that, that's as far as I've been able to get.

Addresses mean nothing to us since you only showed source. Do x/i $pc at the crash to see the faulting instruction. Also verify you have permissions to open /dev/mem. Run the program through strace if that is available.

Check the return values of all your system calls. I'll bet you find that one of them fails. You most likely have to be root to open /dev/mem at all, and depending on other security settings, even that may not be enough.

I am root,  and will do.

Is strace a debugging tool for arm assembly?

@Linklordofgaming strace is a debugging tool for system calls.  It works with programs written in any programming language, including arm assembly.

I'm just gonna say stdin is not a mode, 01066 is neither how you do bitfields nor how you open files, and converting Coul to ASCII hex is not a valid pointer.

What is 01066, and Coul?

The beginning of your devmemerrmessage. Since you do ldr x2, =devmemerrmessage; ldr w2, [x2] you load the first 4 bytes of it. You don't need the ldr.

I found the problem was with the first parameter for x0 in the openat syscall using the x/I $pc thing that you showed me, and which ldr statement are you talking about, I'm assuming the second one, but just want to be sure.

Yeah the second one. The first one loads the address and that's what you need to pass.

The 01066 is the 0666+0200 where the 0200 is wrong, and those are the permission bits anyway not the flags. For the flags you need O_RDWR

Where do I find the values of 0_RDWR, 0_EXCL, 0_RDONLY, 0_WRONLY, and so forth?

In your system header files.

Gotcha, thank you, apologies, I'm relatively new lmao.
